# malloc_consolidate Error while creating new Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, operating-system

I'm trying to create a program that manages simple threads.
This is the main program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  printf("test2:\n--------------\n");
  clock_t stop1;

  uthread_init(100);
  printf ("***%d***\n",uthread_get_tid());
  if(uthread_spawn(f1)==-1)
        printf("FAIL: uthread_spawn failure\n");

  stop1 = clock () + 0.05 * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  int i;    
  printf ("StartLoop of thread: ***%d***\n",uthread_get_tid());
  while(clock ()<stop1) {
    for(i=0;i<10000000;i++) {}
  }
  printf ("FinishLoop of thread: ***%d***\n",uthread_get_tid());

  uthread_terminate(0);
  return 0;
}
```

The code is creating new Thread, which then creates a new thread, which then creats a new Thread. While creating the 3 third, I get the error.
The program stucks here (In the creating thread function):

```
int uthread_spawn(void (*f)(void)) {
DBG(("Spawning !"))
        //checking if number of threads is bigger then max
if (getThreadCount() > MAX_THREAD_NUM){
    errmsgLibrary(MAX_THREADS_LIM);
    return FAIL;
}

// TODO - Check if needed to block/unblock here
if (blockTimerSignal(BLOCK) == SUCCESS){
    DBG(("Block signal success"))
    DBG(("ntid value: %d",nTid))
    pThread t = new Thread(f,nTid++);
    DBG(("new thread created"))
    t->setState(Thread::READY);
    ready.push_back(t);
    DBG(("Added new Thread - %d",(nTid-1)))
    DBG(("Number of threads in ready list is  - %d",(ready.size())))
    blockTimerSignal(UNBLOCK);
    return (nTid-1);
}
DBG(("Block signal not success"))
return FAIL;
}
```

While trying to create new Thread().

The error I get is:

```
test02-new: malloc.c:5161: malloc_consolidate: Assertion `p->fd_nextsize->bk_nextsize == p' failed.
Abort
```

Comment: Sounds like heap corruption.

Comment: What platform? which thread and malloc lib are you using?